# Basic CSS Hover Image-Swap?

Tags: html, css

I'm a super beginner at web development and I have a question about trying to "swap" two images.

I have this CSS and markup written but for some reason it does not seem to be working. The second image that's supposed to swap in when hovering over the first image simply lies on top of the first image on the page.

CSS:

```
.home  {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url('images/onhome.png') no-repeat;
}

.home a, .nav a:link, .nav a:visited {
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 25px;
}

.home a:hover img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="home">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="style/images/home.png" width="65" height="18" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what's going wrong, and I'd be very appreciative if someone can help me. If there's another better way to do this, I would be definitely open to that too.

Comment: Your background image is not an `img`.  Try using `background-position` with a different image instead.

Comment: @Titanium No it doesn't.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 - You're right, I jumped the gun a bit there.

Comment: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/c3bqV/

Comment: It's good practice to have the hover over image in the same image, so it doesn't show blank/whitespace whilst it's loading the hover over image.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to do it is to forget the `<img>`, and on `:hover` change the background-image URL.

```
#home {
    background: url(http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/005/cache/grey-wolf_565_600x450.jpg) no-repeat;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}

#home:hover {
    background: url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6fmnhxL3B1r7wu2mo1_500.jpg)  no-repeat;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/c9sRa/

If you put your cursor over the wolf it will change to a picture tiger cubs :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, going to try this right now and see!

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Another is to use JavaScript. I guess the best way to do it depends on your situation.

Comment: for some reason now I can't even see the full image on the page. Is it because I have a background-image pattern that is covering it up? It looks like the hover effect is working, though.

Comment: You may have to redefine the width/height of the parent element. In my example, I set the div width/height to accomodate both images. That's the thing about the CSS solution :-p

Comment: Ok I did that and it is working now! Thank you so much for the help.