# Display image on mouseover of another image

Tags: html, css, image

If I hover over a image, then display another image on that same image.

[image]

Above image of plane is original image and swapped text is cross transparent image.

If I hover on image of plane then I want to show another image of swapped

Comment: Is this what you are looking to do?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468037/basic-css-hover-image-swap

@Zedai is right also, please show what you have tried first in future.

Comment: @giorgio its a jet ski ;D

Answer (score 4):

The best way to achieve what you are trying to do is to use use jQuery. Please see below:

```
$("#ImageID").mouseover(function(){
    $("#ImageID").attr("src","new/url/goes/here.jpg");
});
$("#ImageID").mouseout(function(){
    $("#ImageID").attr("src","old/url/goes/here.jpg");
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

try this code:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.izo { 
background: url(http://img1.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;  
display: block;
width: 400px; 
height: 400px; 
}

.izo:hover { 
background: url(http://img2.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%; 
} </style> 

<a href="#" class="izo"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, it allow you to **show overlay image without changing original image**

```
<div class="pic-container">
    <div class="pic-box"><img src="img_original.jpg"></div>
    <div class="pic-box pic-hover"><img src="img_original.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

& style

```
<style>
.pic-container{display:block; width:200px; height:200px; position:relative;}
.pic-container .pic-box{display:block; width:200px; height:200px;}
.pic-container .pic-box img{display:block; width:200px; height:200px;}
.pic-container .pic-hover{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; display:none;}
.pic-container:hover .pic-hover{display:block;}
</style>
```