# Replace Images for onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html

The current code is as follows:

```html
<p>
  <a href="../assets/docs/2018 Tax Newsletter.pdf"
     onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" 
     onmouseover="MM_swapImage('fphNews','','../images/fph link final/news links/fphNews-ovr.jpg',1)">
        <img alt="Farmer, Poklop, Hoppa Newsletter"
             border="0"
             height="52"
             id="fphNews"
             name="fphNews"
             src="../images/FPH News/fphNews_Sidebar_2013.gif" width="200" />
  </a>
</p>
```

I need to swap out the `fphNews-ovr.jp`g and `fphNews_Sidebar_2013.gif` images that appear but every time I replace them with the new files (named `fphNews-ovr2018.jpg` and `fphNews_Sidebar_2018.gif` ) it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? What do I need to modify other than the name of the image file?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that changing the URL doesn't change the picture that is displayed?

Comment: @LoganHampton if you format HTML as code (select it and press the `{}` button above the editor) it will appear correctly in your question

Comment: I'm not sure what the functions `MM_swapImgRestore` and `MM_swapImg` do, but it doesn't look like you pass the ID `'fphNews'` into `MM_swapImgRestore`. I'm just taking a guess here, but `MM_swapImgRestore` probably won't know which image to swap out if you don't tell it. Try replacing with `onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore('fphNews')"`.

Comment: Where does PHP come into this? Both of your functions are **JavaScript** functions. I've updated the tags accordingly.

Comment: Please update your question to include all of the relevant code. I do not see definitions for your functions.

Comment: @Plato Yes, changing the file (by physically typing in the name of it, e.g. altering fphNews-ovr.jpg to fphNews-ovr2018.jpg does not display the new image in place of the old one.

Comment: Those function names look like they're from Dreamweaver, which is causing me some harsh flashbacks. Swapping the image files on the web server should work (although you'll need to have viewers empty their cache for it to pick up the new image).

Comment: `MM_swapImage` (from Dreamweaver) is a positively _ancient_ way of swapping images on hover. Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15468037/17300) and answers for modern CSS based methods.